# Connection Time in Google Colab Pro+

Tags: google-colaboratory, mlflow, optuna, dagshub

I am making experiences with mlflow and dagshub, with a public time serie dataset, 3W(https://github.com/petrobras/3W).

I must execute 100 trial with grid search to assess the best set of parameters, using optuna package, and there was some occurrences with the track function.

When I execute the script with less trials in optuna, **it is perfect**, but it is failing when I need to execute more than 4 (four) hours, or 10 trials, from a code running in Colab with optuna, mlflow and dagshub.
Detail: I upgraded from Colab Pro to Colab Pro+, to  execute in background running, where notebooks continue running even after I close the browser tab, as long as I have compute units available..   Now I have 689.98 computing units.

In summary, below we have some trials with fails:
[sumary of trails with fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfGJR.png)

Link to mlflow results:
[text](https://dagshub.com/betomazevedo39/3W.mlflow/#/compare-experiments/s?experiments=%5B%2220%22,%2221%22,%2230%22%5D&searchFilter=&orderByKey=attributes.start_time&orderByAsc=false&startTime=ALL&lifecycleFilter=Active&datasetsFilter=W10%3D&modelVersionFilter=All%20Runs&selectedColumns=attributes.%60Source%60,attributes.%60Models%60,attributes.%60Dataset%60&compareRunCharts=W3sidXVpZCI6IjE3MDAyMjYyOTY5ODZ2emVtZHc4bSIsInR5cGUiOiJCQVIiLCJydW5zQ291bnRUb0NvbXBhcmUiOjEwLCJtZXRyaWNLZXkiOiJhY2N1cmFjeS1hdmcifSx7InV1aWQiOiIxNzAwMjI2Mjk2OTg2ZzkyMTE2dzkiLCJ0eXBlIjoiUEFSQUxMRUwiLCJydW5zQ291bnRUb0NvbXBhcmUiOjEwLCJzZWxlY3RlZFBhcmFtcyI6W10sInNlbGVjdGVkTWV0cmljcyI6W119XQ%3D%3D)

And this is the fail message from Colab on the last trail:

`%%python drive/MyDrive/Mestrado\\ UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py tune -t drive/MyDrive/Mestrado\\ UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/dataset/folds -T drive/MyDrive/Mestrado\\ UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/dataset/folds -e multi_mixed_select_mrl_nonan -n 30`

Error message:

> [2023-11-17 01:14:47,193 - tune_lgbm_colab - INFO] model.predict
> [W 2023-11-17 01:15:06,354] Trial 22 failed with parameters: {'level': 10, 'importance_percentile': 0.6893999015182921, 'normal_balance': 4, 'subsample': 0.2, 'feature_fraction': 0.45000000000000007, 'lambda_l1': 4.473491485855139, 'lambda_l2': 0.646775882590484, 'num_leaves': 127} because of the following error: MlflowException('API request to endpoint /api/2.0/mlflow/runs/update failed with error code 400 != 200. Response body: '"repo not associated with run"'').
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Mestrado UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py", line 275, in objective
> log_results(results)
> File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Mestrado UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py", line 145, in log_results
> mlflow.log_metric("score-std", np.std(results["scores"]))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 771, in log_metric
> return MlflowClient().log_metric(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 766, in log_metric
> return self._tracking_client.log_metric(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 298, in log_metric
> self.store.log_metric(run_id, metric)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 198, in log_metric
> self._call_endpoint(LogMetric, req_body)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 59, in _call_endpoint
> return call_endpoint(self.get_host_creds(), endpoint, method, json_body, response_proto)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 210, in call_endpoint
> response = verify_rest_response(response, endpoint)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 148, in verify_rest_response
> raise MlflowException(
> mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to endpoint /api/2.0/mlflow/runs/log-metric failed with error code 400 != 200. Response body: '"repo not associated with run"'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 200, in _run_trial
> value_or_values = func(trial)
> File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Mestrado UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py", line 270, in objective
> with mlflow.start_run(nested=True, run_name=f"trial - {trial.number} - cv"):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 190, in **exit**
> end_run(RunStatus.to_string(status))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 446, in end_run
> MlflowClient().set_terminated(_last_active_run_id, status)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 1909, in set_terminated
> self._tracking_client.set_terminated(run_id, status, end_time)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 575, in set_terminated
> self.store.update_run_info(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 151, in update_run_info
> response_proto = self._call_endpoint(UpdateRun, req_body)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 59, in _call_endpoint
> return call_endpoint(self.get_host_creds(), endpoint, method, json_body, response_proto)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 210, in call_endpoint
> response = verify_rest_response(response, endpoint)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 148, in verify_rest_response
> raise MlflowException(
> mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to endpoint /api/2.0/mlflow/runs/update failed with error code 400 != 200. Response body: '"repo not associated with run"'
> [W 2023-11-17 01:15:06,358] Trial 22 failed with value None.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Mestrado UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py", line 275, in objective
> log_results(results)
> File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Mestrado UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py", line 145, in log_results
> mlflow.log_metric("score-std", np.std(results["scores"]))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 771, in log_metric
> return MlflowClient().log_metric(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 766, in log_metric
> return self._tracking_client.log_metric(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 298, in log_metric
> self.store.log_metric(run_id, metric)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 198, in log_metric
> self._call_endpoint(LogMetric, req_body)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 59, in _call_endpoint
> return call_endpoint(self.get_host_creds(), endpoint, method, json_body, response_proto)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 210, in call_endpoint
> response = verify_rest_response(response, endpoint)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 148, in verify_rest_response
> raise MlflowException(
> mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to endpoint /api/2.0/mlflow/runs/log-metric failed with error code 400 != 200. Response body: '"repo not associated with run"'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ### Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Mestrado UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py", line 496, in 
> cli(obj={})
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in **call**
> return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
> rv = self.invoke(ctx)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
> return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
> return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
> return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
> return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
> File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Mestrado UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py", line 457, in tune
> study = hyperparameter_search(
> File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Mestrado UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py", line 300, in hyperparameter_search
> study.optimize(objective, config["num_trials"], callbacks=[mlflow_callback])
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/optuna/study/study.py", line 451, in optimize
> _optimize(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 66, in _optimize
> _optimize_sequential(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 163, in _optimize_sequential
> frozen_trial = _run_trial(study, func, catch)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 251, in _run_trial
> raise func_err
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/optuna/study/_optimize.py", line 200, in _run_trial
> value_or_values = func(trial)
> File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Mestrado UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py", line 270, in objective
> with mlflow.start_run(nested=True, run_name=f"trial - {trial.number} - cv"):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 190, in **exit**
> end_run(RunStatus.to_string(status))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 446, in end_run
> MlflowClient().set_terminated(_last_active_run_id, status)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 1909, in set_terminated
> self._tracking_client.set_terminated(run_id, status, end_time)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 575, in set_terminated
> self.store.update_run_info(
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 151, in update_run_info
> response_proto = self._call_endpoint(UpdateRun, req_body)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 59, in _call_endpoint
> return call_endpoint(self.get_host_creds(), endpoint, method, json_body, response_proto)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 210, in call_endpoint
> response = verify_rest_response(response, endpoint)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 148, in verify_rest_response
> raise MlflowException(
> mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to endpoint /api/2.0/mlflow/runs/update failed with error code 400 != 200. Response body: '"repo not associated with run"'
>
> CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in <cell line: 1>()
> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('python', 'drive/MyDrive/Mestrado\ UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/training/multiclass/tune_lgbm_colab3.py tune -t drive/MyDrive/Mestrado\ UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/dataset/folds -T drive/MyDrive/Mestrado\ UFRJ/3W/toolkit/MAIS/dataset/folds -e multi_mixed_select_mrl_nonan -n 30', '')
>
> 4 frames
>  in shebang(self, line, cell)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in shebang(self, line, cell)
> 243             sys.stderr.flush()
> 244         if args.raise_error and p.returncode!=0:
> 245             raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cell, output=out, stderr=err)
> 246
> 247     def _run_script(self, p, cell, to_close):
>
> CalledProcessError: Command 'b' \n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.

If you could give some light, I am very grateful !!!

I tried to run with less trials and it was ok.